How to check if one dictionary containing list is a subset of another dictionary with list in python
Hi I have two dictionaries defined which contains lists
dict_1 = {'V1': ['2024-11-07', '2024-11-08'], 'V2': ['2024-11-07', '2024-11-08']}
dict_2 = {'V1': ['2024-11-08'], 'V2': ['2024-11-07']}

both items (key and val) from dict_2 above are subset of dict_1 so I wanted return true in both cases.
I tried to use res = set(dict_2.items()).issubset(set(dict_1.items()))
However it works if its simple dictionary like
dict_1 = {'abc' : 1, 'pqr' : 2} 
dict_2 = {'abc' : 1} 

in my case is there any way this can be done?

You can check for each key of dict_2 that its sublist is a subset of the corresponding sublist of dict_1:
def dict_issubset(maybe_subset, maybe_superset):
    return {
        key: set(sublist).issubset(maybe_superset[key])
        for key, sublist in maybe_subset.items()
    }

so that:
dict_1 = {'V1': ['2024-11-07', '2024-11-08'], 'V2': ['2024-11-07', '2024-11-08']}
dict_2 = {'V1': ['2024-11-08'], 'V2': ['2024-11-07']}
print(dict_issubset(dict_2, dict_1))

outputs:
{'V1': True, 'V2': True}

Demo: https://ideone.com/wuvTET

What does maybe_subset.keys() <= maybe_superset.keys() check?

It checks that the keys of maybe_subset is a subset of the keys of maybe_superset. In other words, it checks that maybe_subset doesn't have any keys that maybe_superset doesn't have.

I wanted to check whether 'V1': ['2024-11-08'] is subset of 'V1': ['2024-11-07', '2024-11-08'] and 'V2': ['2024-11-07'] is subset of 'V2': ['2024-11-07', '2024-11-08'] where key matches, In above code I would expect two output for each item from dict_2. So there should be two 'True'. If I change dict_2 item to 'V1': ['2024-11-09'] the output should be false and true. The above code wont do that.

@Sachin I've updated the answer accordingly then.

by the way I never used return like that. Is there any way to get only true or false rather than keys (V1 and V2)

@Sachin If the keys of your dicts are always ordered in the same way then you can return just the values instead, i.e. return [set(sublist).issubset(maybe_superset[key]) for key, sublist in maybe_subset.values()]

@Sachin If you only want a single true or false value for the whole dict, you could use all({set(sublist).issubset(maybe_superset[key]) for key, sublist in maybe_subset.items()}. This returns true if the condition holds for all keys. There's also any which returns true if it holds for at least one item.
